# How to get the time since post published on praw

Tags: python, bots, reddit, praw

I'm writing a bot using `praw` and I want to know how time has past since a post have been published. The naive solution is to use `datetime`

```
import datetime
import praw

... """read a list of submission"""

date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(submission.created)
dif = datetime.datetime.now() - date
```

But I get negative time stamps. I guess I need to take into account reddit's time zone, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is special function that will return utc epoch time.

```
import datetime
import praw

... #stuff

date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(submission.created_utc)
dif = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - date
```

utcnow() returns your current time as it appears in Universal Time. Same with submission.created_utc

For future reference you can dynamically check what functions/vars are available in each praw object (this is much more reliable than documentation).

```
from pprint import pprint
object = ... #any praw object like praw.Reddit praw.Submission praw.Comment etc
pprint(dir(object))
pprint(vars(object))
```